# Ruby on Rails checkbox got validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some issue with rails checkbox validation in the has_many. It's says checkbox need to exist even though I lardy checked the box. I include my code down below.

**Role.rb (Modal)**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :role_permission_ids
    has_many :users, dependent: :nullify
    belongs_to :role_permission

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
    # validates_acceptance_of :role_permission_ids
end
```

**RolePermission.rb (Modal)**

```
class RolePermission < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :roles
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<% @title="Add Role" %>
<h1 class="center">Add role</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_with(model: @role, local: true, data: { turbo: false }) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

            <%= f.label :name, class: 'required' %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', required: true %>

            <%= f.label :description, class: 'required' %>
            <%= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control', required: true %>

            <%= f.label :role_permission, class: 'required' %>
            <% RolePermission.all.each do |role_permission| %>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <%= check_box_tag "role[role_permission_ids][]", role_permission.id %>
                    <%= role_permission.permission %>
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <%= f.submit "Create Role", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <%= link_to 'Back', roles_path, class: 'btn btn-success', style: 'width: 39.7em' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I try to register new role it shows `Role permission must exist` error in the User Interface(UI)
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgU7K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your role_permission is a belongs_to and what you have setup is going to pass an array which will not work. Im assuming what you actually want is a polymorphic association. check out: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html